# Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved:

Tags: maven, jenkins, artifactory

while trying to build my maven application and deploying the artifacts on jfrog It is showing an error that the it cannot find the artifact release to be more specific the error log is shown below .

```
[main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:3.1.0: Could not find artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugins:pom:31 in artifactory-release (http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-release) -> [Help 1]
```

my jenkins pipeline looks something like this

```
node {

def server
def buildInfo
def rtMaven
def mvnHome = tool 'Maven3'

stage ("checkout")  {
   git 'https://github.com/methelegend-sys/fisrt_jenkins'
}

  stage ('Artifactory configuration') {
    server = Artifactory.server('artifactory-server');
    rtMaven = Artifactory.newMavenBuild()
    rtMaven.tool = 'Maven3'
    rtMaven.deployer releaseRepo: 'libs-release-local', snapshotRepo: 'libs-snapshot-local', server: server
    rtMaven.resolver releaseRepo: 'libs-release', snapshotRepo: 'libs-snapshot', server: server
    //rtMaven.deployer.deployArtifacts = false // Disable artifacts deployment during Maven run

    //buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()
    //rtMaven.tool = 'Maven3' // Tool name from Jenkins configuration
    //rtMaven.deployer releaseRepo:'example-repo-local', snapshotRepo:'example-repo-local', server: server
    //rtMaven.resolver releaseRepo:'example-repo-local', snapshotRepo:'example-repo-local', server: server
    buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()
  }
  
   stage ('Build') {
       //bat 'mvn clean install'
        rtMaven.run -X pom: 'pom.xml', goals: 'clean install', buildInfo: buildInfo
    }
   
    stage ('Upload Artifacts') {
        rtMaven.deployer.deployArtifacts buildInfo
       server.publishBuildInfo buildInfo
    }
}
```

my settings.xml file looks something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <proxies>
  
    <proxy>
      <id>optional</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <username>proxyuser</username>
      <password>proxypass</password>
      <host>proxy.host.net</host>
      <port>80</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>

  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>deploymentRepo</id>
      <username>repouser</username>
      <password>repopwd</password>
    </server>
    <server>
      <id>siteServer</id>
      <privateKey>/path/to/private/key</privateKey>
      <passphrase>optional; leave empty if not used.</passphrase>
    </server>
  </servers>

  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>mirrorId</id>
      <mirrorOf>repositoryId</mirrorOf>
      <name>Human Readable Name for this Mirror.</name>
      <url>http://my.repository.com/repo/path</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
<profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>jdk-1.4</id>

      <activation>
        <jdk>1.4</jdk>
      </activation>

      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>jdk14</id>
          <name>Repository for JDK 1.4 builds</name>
          <url>http://www.myhost.com/maven/jdk14</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
          <snapshotPolicy>always</snapshotPolicy>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>env-dev</id>

      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>target-env</name>
          <value>dev</value>
        </property>
      </activation>

      <properties>
        <tomcatPath>/path/to/tomcat/instance</tomcatPath>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>alwaysActiveProfile</activeProfile>
    <activeProfile>anotherAlwaysActiveProfile</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
  </settings>
```

I cant figure it out why the build looks for plugin in local repository instead of remote repository .

When I try building without writing a jenkins file it also gets built successfully but not In case of jenkins file .

Comment: There is probably an error in the `settings.xml` because you try to read the maven plugin from a repository that looks like your internal release repository.

Comment: yes that is the issue and I am wondering how can I solve that I tried looking in settings.xml file but everything looks fine there even if I build this application in eclipse it works fine and downloads every plugin from remote repository but not in jenkins

Comment: Then you probably have a different `settings.xml` on Jenkins or you have already loaded a lot of stuff into the local repository on your computer. Please add the `settings.xml` to the question.

Comment: Done that please have a look

Comment: Why is jdk = 1.4 under <activation> instead of 14 ?